# Does anyone know how to kill this unused secret boss/enemy?

Tags: nintendo-nightmare

In Nintendo Nightmare, one has the ability to use cheat codes which are lines of code within Game Maker's system (the software has a function specifically for this and the game uses it).

This led to me looking at a few of the assets, one of which caught my attention very deeply. There appears to be a hidden boss with the object name "obj_bigchampi". It appears to be like any of the other big chu-chu monsters in the dungeons of the second part, except it has a mushroom textured band around the middle section of the body. It also randomly spawns boulders on top of the player (which are nothing more than the kind that block paths, thereby immobilizing the player and utterly ruining the camera's angle).

I'm trying to figure out how to kill it (beyond just cheating its life to 0).

I've tried all of link's weapons and a few of the weapons lying around hyrule field. Does anyone have any idea how to kill this thing? It seems like it is invincible, and the rock attack makes it seem even stranger.

Also here is an image of the boss. I think there has to be a way to remove its armor. I just cannot seem to determine how.

[image: obj_bigchampi]

Bonus points for whomever can identify what sort of abomination that thing is supposed to be!

Comment: @TimmyJim so... should I delete the question?

Comment: At this point, it wouldn't hurt.  Eventually, the community can vote on deleting the question as well after it's been on hold for long enough.

Comment: @TimmyJim Alright. And since this and the other question were found to be similar questions (because they are about the same game) should i add this question to the body of the other question so that I can still potentially receive an answer to this question? The other question doesn't mention the enemy in this question. It just asks about finding hidden secrets in the game, which at the time I presumed involved this asset which is why this question was spawned. I don't mind deleting it, but I would still like to find an answer to this someday...

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. It's talking about a different enemy than the other question, just in the same game.

Comment: @murgatroid99 thank you. Sorry for voting to close it before. I didn't realize this question was allowed as separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the source code and objects within the same organizational regions of the game, it would appear that this enemy being unkillable is nothing more than a bug. All other enemies within the same region have their parent object set as a generic enemy object. This one doesn't. Hence, anything that hits it does absolutely nothing. Also, looking through the code and searching heavily, there appear to be no direct ways to kill it aside from cheating. So, it would appear that the only way to kill it is with the following cheat code.

> with (obj_bigchampi) {instance_destroy();}

So, it would seem that this object serves as nothing more than an annoying ugly rock wall spawner that follows you around. Now I understand why it was removed.